# ADFDI spreadsheet table rendering getting exception

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I was trying to generate a spreadsheet containing the result of a VO query in a table format using ADF DI. It is erroring out with the following exception 
Failed to retrieve table row data from the server. (ADFDI-05577)
unable to set position to row 680 (ADFDI-55045)

```
~~~~~~~~~~
DownloadFailedException: Failed to retrieve table row data from the server. (ADFDI-05577)
Source: adfdi-excel-runtime
Stack: 
   at oracle.adf.client.windows.excel.runtime.uicomponent.table.TableDownloadHelper.ReadMultiSyncRow(MultiSyncRow msr)
   at oracle.adf.client.windows.excel.runtime.uicomponent.table.TableDownloadHelper.FlushMultiSyncRowsToCache()
   at oracle.adf.client.windows.excel.runtime.uicomponent.table.TableDownloadHelper.DoDownload()
   at oracle.adf.client.windows.excel.runtime.uicomponent.table.TableDownloadHelper.Download()
   at oracle.adf.client.windows.excel.runtime.uicomponent.table.TableActionHelper.DownloadTableData(DownloadType downloadType)
   at oracle.adf.client.windows.excel.runtime.uicomponent.table.TableActionHelper.Invoke(RTComponentAction rtAction)
   at oracle.adf.client.windows.excel.runtime.uicomponent.RTBaseTable.Invoke(RTComponentAction rtAction)
   at oracle.adf.client.windows.excel.runtime.uicomponent.RTComponentAction.Invoke()
   at oracle.adf.client.windows.excel.runtime.uicomponent.RTActionCollection.DoInvoke()
Inner:
AdfdiException: unable to set position to row 680 (ADFDI-55045)
Stack:
```

The VO query executes fine in sql developer and also same query is reused in another application which runs fine too(the query was used in another application for displaying data in UI not spreadsheet).Please advice on any possible solution.

No matching exception is found in server logs.

In the spreadsheet level , it throws the exception and after we click on oK , it displays rows upto 680

Comment: It may be throwing as it's not matching spreadsheet errors.. Try to get one single row. even if you are getting exception then try to fetch few columns and check on which error you are getting exception.

Comment: and check that particular 681th row

Comment: turns out changing the iterator range size to -1 fixed the issue in standalone server....dont know why this is needed only needed in standalone server though